# Hadoop 2.4 Native Library problems

Tags: hadoop

I am using `Hadoop 2.4.0` in Ubuntu 13 64 bit machine. Hadoop is successfully installed but at the time of running basic commands like

`#hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp`

I am getting the following error :

```
 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

After deeply understand the problem it comes me that the problem occurs because of `32/64` bit native library compatibility issue. I've already re-build hadoop src by maven distribution as suggested by several blogs.

But the problem still persist. Unable to find any solution?

Comment: Can you update your post with the results of the `hadoop checknative`command?

Answer (score 0):

First this is just a warning, which can be ignored.

Here is the way if you do want to eliminate this warning, download the source code of Hadoop and recompile hadoop on 64bit system, then replace the 32bit one.

Steps on how to recompile source code are included here for Ubuntu:

http://www.ercoppa.org/Linux-Compile-Hadoop-220-fix-Unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library.htm
http://www.csrdu.org/nauman/2014/01/23/geting-started-with-hadoop-2-2-0-building/

Answer (score 0):

Move your compiled native library files to $HADOOP_HOME/lib folder.

Then set your environment variables by editing .bashrc file

export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"

Make sure your compiled native library files are in $HADOOP_HOME/lib folder.

it should work.